# How compare data value get from ajax call database with html input value in realtime

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I try to compare two data values .
one value get from database by ajax jquery call

```
function marketbuyshow(){

  $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/showmarketbuydata",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {

   $("#balance").html("");
            $.each(response.balancedata,function(key,item){
              $('#balance').append('<span>'+item.mybalance+'</span>');
                      
            });
```

other one get from input value. I have this form for data input , price / amount / total input

```
                  <form>
                          <div class="title"> </div>
                          <div >Avaliable Balance : <span id="balance"></span></div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Price</label>
                          <input type="text" id="price" required class="price form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Amount</label>
                          <input type="text" id="amount" required class="amount form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Total</label>
                          <input type="text" id="total" required class="total form-control" readonly />
                         
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnn" class="btn btn-primary marketbuy">Buy</button>
                      </form>
```

if total value greater than avaliable balance
I want to disable buy button by jquery as follow
but this balance value not work.
Although show data in frontend,
it pass with empty string and cannot compare in real time.

```
 let balan = $('#balance').val();
       console.log(balan);
       let total = $('#total').val();
       console.log(total);
if(total >balan){
         console.log($('#total').val());
         $("#btnn").attr("disabled", true);
       }else{
       // console.log("total is less than ");
        $("#btnn").attr("disabled", false);
       }
```

[image]

How can I get balance value in realtime and can compare whenever total values get in inputform .
How can I do this .
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of getting the span contents:

https://jsfiddle.net/642s8nau/2/

```
<form>
  <div class="title"> </div>
  <div >Avaliable Balance : <span id="balance">1000</span></div>
  <div >Another Value : <span id="anotherValue">500</span></div>
  <button type="button" id="getValues" class="btn btn-primary">Compare Values</button>
</form>  
    
$(document).on("click", "#getValues", function (event) {
    alert(Number($("#balance").text()) > Number($("#anotherValue").text()));
});
```

Comment: please read my codes. I just use this balance to compare with total ,why need to click button

Comment: You told me text doesn't work.  I was showing you that you can get the contents of a span using .text().  If it doesn't work in a comparison, you may need to make sure both values are being treated as numbers: w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp.

Comment: I update the fiddle to compare two numbers from two span tags.  You can change the values and see that it works.

Comment: thanks bro, the main problem is balance value is dynamically get from ajax call database,So this value not get when call by your way. How can solve this

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then because if it's on the page, you can get it.  Doesn't really matter when it got there.  If it's before it's on the page, like in your ajax response, why not keep a running total of you item.mybalance or whatever it is?

Answer (score 0):

Span won't have a val().  If you want to use val(), make it a readonly input.  You could also use .text() to get what's in the span.

Comment: text() not work, only empty string pass.

Comment: Try making it a readonly input and then using val() as you were. <label for="">Available Balance</label>
 <input type="text" id="balance" required class="form-control readonly" />

Comment: yes I already try this , but this balance value not work when compare ,

Comment: You can use the js number fuction on the values to make sure they are being evaluated as such.  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/642s8nau/2/

Answer (score 0):

**General idea of solution:**

For real time you might consider using Socket.io (HTML version). This way you will create a direct, two-way connection with your Server. This way you can push the new value to the client whenever it changes in the backend. Anytime you write in the input, you could in the onChange compare the user input with the current value pushed by Socke.io, which will constantly update in real time.

**Why do I recommend Socket.io?**

Forgive me, I took apart your entire code and I am aware of that, however, I wanted to make you aware of a slightly different handling of the problem. Socket.io is a clean solution in that the server contacts you only when that value actually changes and so client-side you don't need long polling or anything like that.